# C# Как определить что мышка наведена на квадрат

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть много квадратов на PictureBox (top, left, right, bottom) мне нужно выделять квадрат когда курсор на нем. Как быстро искать квадрат? Их может быть к примеру 100, и если я навожу на сотый, то цикл зря сравнивает 99 штук + время

Comment: Скорость поиска уже для вас стала реальной проблемой? Или это преждевременная оптимизация?

Comment: @VladD преждевременная

Comment: @MikeWaters не могли бы вы скинуть исходники программы?

Comment: 100 проверок - это пшик по сравнению с работой, которую делает GUI "за кулисами"

Comment: Если задача без "одновременного" нахождения -  то тут два варианта 1) перебор. 2)  завести 2Д-массив каждый из елементов которых квадрат. Решенее емкое по-памяти, но очень быстро ищет. Ну и можно делать вариации... 1+2 в разных долях.

Comment: Как вариант 3 - можно разбить экран по зонам кратно разрешению (массив 2D)- и обьединять обьекты (квадраты) в зоны (массив) - тогда возможен "двоичный" поиск по-зонам, но это сложнее.

Comment: Для сотни объектов, думаю, перебор быстрее всего. Но в общем случае вам может пригодиться это: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_(computational_geometry)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что оптимальнее всего нужно создать функцию по поиску квадратов на изображении, которая будет хранить список ВСЕХ квадратов на картинке.

Формально, тебе нужно создать List и в него записать все что тебе нужно. Алгоритм поиска каждого отдельного квадрата -- на тебе уже.

Потом все просто: ты просто проверяешь находится ли мышка в этих областях (с учетом сдвига левой верхней точки относительно левой верхней точки экрана -- окно же можно двигать по экрану).

Эту штуку ты реализуешь внутри OnMouseMove твоего PictureBox.

Отрисовка наведения на квадрат делается по +- этому же принципу. Только ты просто закрашиваешь этот квадрат в красный цвет, например. Координаты квадрата внутри pictureBox у тебя уже есть.